# Adding Octomap data to planning scene in ROS Electric

Tags: ros, octomap, planning-scene, arm-navigation, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use data from an octomap for collision avoidance in arm_navigation. Octomap_server publishes a series of collision objects on the octomap_collision_object topic so I was hoping that I could use these but this does not work (I tried remapping to the collision_object topic). Is this something that would have worked in diamondback but doesn't with the electric planning scene architecture? How can I add the octomap data to the arm_navigation planning scene in ROS electric? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30426/adding-octomap-data-to-planning-scene-in-ros-electric/) by [jwrobbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1711/jwrobbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2012-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe the version of octomap_server for Electric doesn't publish the collision map. I have a version of octomap_server that was ported from Diamondback to Electric that does publish a collision map on "collision_map_out".

You can see the version here:

https://sbpl.pc.cs.cmu.edu/redmine/projects/full-body-nav/repository/revisions/master/show/octomap_server

You can get the code:

```
git clone https://sbpl.pc.cs.cmu.edu/redmine/people/mike/full-body-nav.git
```

I know that that version works and does what you want.

---

Originally posted by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) with karma: 674 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jwrobbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1711/jwrobbo/) on 2012-03-28**:
Thanks! Works like a charm. Looks like you're working on a pretty interesting project.

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2012-03-28**:
Happy to hear it. It seems like you are as well :)

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-04-03**:
Collision map publishing on the same topic has now been backported to octomap_server in octomap_mapping (trunk).